# HTTPS - Amazon Load Balancer with certificates

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing

I'm having some trouble using Amazon Load Balancer with HTTPS.

I already have a certificate and it's already configured.

Using curl, when I test load balance servers separately, I don't find any error.

But testing with load balancing address (curl -v "https_domain_name") it returns the following message:

"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

The certificate is valid and the name match the domain name in URL.

Comment: Is it a new cert? It may have not yet saturated around the CAs?

Comment: It's an old one =/ ...and it's working... but doesn't work with Amazon LB =/

Comment: And you've gone through all of the AWS docs on it? It's a complicated process to get working, and that error is too generic to really pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I know =/ I'm reading for like.. 2 hours LOL.. must be a simple and a difficult problem at the same time hahaha.. but thank you r3mus! Appreciate your help! =)

Comment: Yeah, I've always struggled with AWS getting things to work. Wish I could be more help, sorry!

Comment: No problem r3mus! I will answer here if I find the answer =D ...don't feel sorry =D Appreciate your help! ;)

Comment: What about web browsers? What do they say when you try to connect? Did you install the Intermediate/CA Bundle Cert on the ELB? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111829/ec2-load-balancer-installing-ca-bundle-ssl-intermediate-certificate

Comment: In browser I can connect.. using cURL I get that error message.. Guess that this is happening while generating those 3 keys (private, public and chain) for Amazon =/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the domain names may be different on the servers and the ELB.

Are you running curl to the ELB address or to the DNS CNAME that you setup for that server (you should run in to the CNAME).

The ELB addresses are something like this:

```
TestLB-1268527133.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

The CNAME should be something like

```
www.yourdomain.com
```

If you're running to the CNAME, does it match the domain name on the cert ? In other words does it have the same domain domain as the server behind the ELB. Also, keep in mind that if you have multiple severs running behind an ELB running SSL you need a star cert. For example `*.yourcomain.com`

Comment: I'm running with CNAME. I solved it using this article: http://cloudarch.co.uk/2011/10/elastic-load-balancer-ssl-setup-guide-pem-encoded-csr/#.UrGbIvRXXnq

Comment: Thanks for the help Rico! and r3mus and Michael... thank you too =)

Comment: The url with the solution as @Crasher posted (http://cloudarch.co.uk/...) is broken :(
Can anyone post the exact solution here please ? thanks.